# pkg-config: command not found error

Tags: r, hadoop

I am setting up R with Hadoop. I am getting the following error on installing package "rhbase": (other packages[see below] and their dependencies have been installed successfully)

bash-3.2$ ls
plyrmr_0.4.0.tar    rhbase_1.2.1.tar    rhdfs_1.0.8.tar     rmr2_3.2.0.tar

ERROR:

```
> install.packages("/Users/raunak/Downloads/rlibs/rhbase_1.2.1.tar", repos = NULL, type="source")
* installing *source* package ‘rhbase’ ...
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I. -g -DHAVE_UINTPTR_T -DHAVE_NETDB_H=1 -fpermissive -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -I./gen_cpp `pkg-config --cflags thrift` -Wall -fPIC -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2 -c Hbase.cpp -o Hbase.o
/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
In file included from Hbase.cpp:7:
./Hbase.h:10:10: fatal error: 'TProcessor.h' file not found
\#include <TProcessor.h>
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Hbase.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rhbase’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/rhbase’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘/Users/raunak/Downloads/rlibs/rhbase_1.2.1.tar’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

bash-3.2$ which pkg-config

/usr/local/bin/pkg-config

What could be the cause?

Comment: It seems that you are missing some system libraries. Reading from https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/user%3Erhbase%3EHome it seems that `Thrift` is needed to install `rhbase`.

Comment: There also a potential for homebrew or Macports installations of external packages not being found by the standard R installations, but I don't know if that applies to RevoR.  (And it would have been ideal if you included more detail on your versions of OSX, R, XCode and how XCode is set up.)

Comment: @nicola: I need to install thrift version 0.9.0 but the command "brew install thrift" installs the latest version (0.9.1). How can i do this?

Comment: http://archive.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.9.0/